# Явление или явленье?

Tags: орфография

Здравствуйте?

Явление или явленье?

Или можно и так и так?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Явление. Слово книжного стиля, значение процесса - выбираем  форму на -ние. Хотя в поэтической речи возможно и явленье как требование ритма и рифмы.